# Sentences start with a verb

Tags: grammar

I spotted that sometimes sentences may start with a verb (e.g. "suppose" and "imagine", as shown in the below example sentence). May I ask apart from "suppose" and "imagine", if there are any other verbs that can be used in this way? Also, is this type of sentence only suitable for some less formal texts, and should they be avoided in some formal ones? Thanks.

Examples:
''Imagine a woman in love with her own body.'' ([source](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=oQGmL42SSkIC&pg=PP43&dq=.%20Imagine&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWzd2Fv6PmAhUYa94KHWSYDKwQ6AEIYzAG#v=onepage&q=.%20Imagine&f=false))
''Suppose it has turned the hair white.''([source](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=xakp4JmBXjUC&pg=PT328&dq=.%20Suppose&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjonemxv6PmAhUOFogKHX3YB0Q4ChDoAQhKMAQ#v=onepage&q=.%20Suppose&f=false))

Comment: It's an ***imperative*** construction - with deleted subject ***you***. A normal feature of English, unrelated to concepts of formal / informal language.

Comment: "Consider the lilies, how they grow" (Luke 12:27)

Comment: thank you both for your answers, which are helpful!

Comment: Any imperative. *Run like the wind!* *Drop the gun!* Here's one that's not an imperative: *Smile and the whole world smiles with you.*